# How is it possible for the Navigation Bar title to not be aligned in centre only on one specific view?

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, swift2, uinavigationbar

In my application I have 9 different menu items and all of them have the navigation bar title centred. There is only one view in which the title it seems to be aligned right (see screen 2 attached). How is this possible?

The screen 1 & 2 that I have attached are two consecutive screens, in which the 1st title is ok and then wrong. Any suggestions?

[image: screen 2]
[image: screen 1]

Comment: you might have added spaces,

Comment: spaces where? I did not mess with the nav bar.

Comment: count the character of your titlestring

Comment: In the string "Scuba diving"..it might be set like this "              Scuba diving"

Comment: 1st title is also not centered. :)

Comment: I actually thought so too! I can't get it! No of characters is correct!

Comment: Have you checked with setting navigation tittle label to centre and background colour to any other colour ?

Comment: @sourav yes!! and it is all fine!

Comment: perhaps your view / view controller is not sized correctly. Do you use auto layout? Try on a different screen size - it's probably in the middle already, but the nav bar is cutting off.

Comment: @Stephenye yes I am using auto layout! I have spent the last few hours trying everything but can't fix it.

Comment: Do you just use : self.title = "whatever" ?

Comment: @JohnD yes exactly that!

Comment: Did you see anything suspicious when debugging the view hierarchy? Also try to add a right-hand side nav bar button to see if it can be positioned correctly.

Comment: Your left hand nav bar button doesn't look like a normal button. That's customized isn't it? Could have spaces/margin that's weird with that specific button

Comment: @JohnD no it's not a custom button!! The strangest thing of all is that all the other views I have are working fine. Also  I didn't notice anything strange. I will try what you suggested .

Answer (score 0):

Okay after having tried everything I realised that I had used the code below in the app delegate to **hide** the title of the back button:

```
 let barAppearace = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()
    barAppearace.setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(0, -60), forBarMetrics:UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

As a result, my actual back title which was longer that all the other titles in the rest of my views (this is why all my other views worked fine) was still there but **hidden**, **pushing** the main nav title to the right as it was too long.

Therefore to avoid this issue ensure that you have not hidden the title of the back button.